# WPF binding visibility to gridview listview button

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatrigger

How do I bind the visibility of a button inside a listview without using converter, but using the data trigger property. But i not manage to understand how to code behind. Do we still need to  use Boolean property to hold the true/ false value? If yes, how to implement that? Sorry that i am new to WPF, and still not able to understand those complex code badly.

private void Btnfolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
        try
        {
            // the excel file open from here to display gridview with button true and false for certain rows but i do not know how to set the visibility here

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    public bool _isVisible = false;
    public bool IsVisible
    {

        get { return _isVisible; }

        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible"); --> error- cannot convert from string to  System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs 
        }
    }
                 <GridViewColumn Header="View CriticalPart" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="btnCritical"  Content="Edit" Click="Button_Click" Width="80" Height="30" Margin="5"   >
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: The "root cause" of your problem is that you directly access the Button. Bind its Visibility to a property of the data item class, or set it by a DataTrigger.

Comment: @Clemens the data item class are you meaning view model class? I have studied that but i have no idea how to apply that because the application is already developed without view model class..could you provide me an example for those you explained? Thanks.

Comment: You mean an example for binding the Visibility to a boolean property? The internet is full of that.

Comment: Hi @Clemens 2 months later i still not able to solve this issue, seriously can you show me an example, i have been struggling to study a lot about the boolean converter but still no able to understand that so badly, really upset  :(

Comment: @Clemens  I want to use this way but not able to find out how to use it correctly at code behind, can you advise?     <Style TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

Comment: Is there a boolean property in the item class (i.e. the element type of the ItemsSource collection) that would control the visibility of the Button in the ItemTemplate? Maybe edit your question with some details about what you are actually trying to achieve. Also note that you would not use a ListView unless you set its View property. If you only set an ItemTemplate, better use the simpler ListBox class.

Comment: I am using ListView inside a grid using usercontrol instead of window. I am not using the method of the current post anymore and plan to use the data trigger. Sorry that i am really new to WPF, what do you mean set its View property? Can i personally contact you?

Comment: You could edit your question with all relevant details, or write a new one.

Comment: @Clemens i have edited the post, can you help?

Comment: When you write `Binding="{Binding IsVisible}"` in the DataTrigger, there should be an IsVisible property in the item class. I think I already asked that. Is there such a property? Does it fire a change notification?

Comment: I have edited the post with added the property, i do not know how to apply the property correctly so it doesnt fire. Addition it have error..

Comment: Please read about how to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It seems you have the IsVisible property in some UI element class. As said, it should be in the *item* class, i.e. the *element type* of the source collection of the ListView's ItemsSource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224802/discussion-between-ashley-hooithin-and-clemens).